# Need to upgrade to Spring Framework 5.x.x while remaining on Spring Data GemFire 1.3.4; Is there anyway to ensure a smooth transition?

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

Our project used to depend on spring 3.x.x and 4.x.x, while it has to upgrade to 5.3.18 due to the vulnerabilities security department require to handle.

we strong depend on gemfire 8.2.5 and it cannot upgrade due to many many reasons. we use gemfire with spring-data-gemfire 1.3.4 which depends on spring 3.x.x (4.x.x is also compatible).

When we upgrade to spring 5.x.x, the compatible problems occur such as most important usage about BeanFactoryLocator, it has been removed in the spring 5.x.x. Maybe there are other compatible problems as well.

So want to ask if there is anyway to remain spring 5.x.x and spring-data-gemfire 1.3.4 unchange and also solve the incompatible problems. Such as some bridge dependency to confirm spring smooth transition?

Answer (score 1):

In short... NO.

There is no simple way to reconcile the differences between *Spring Data GemFire* `1.3.4` (which has long been out of Spring OSS support, BTW), that was [based on](https://In%20short...%20NO.%20%20There%20is%20no%20simple%20way%20to%20bridge%20between%20Spring%20Data%20GemFire%201.3.4%20(which%20is%20long%20out%20of%20Spring%20OSS%20support),) Spring Framework `3.2.x` (specifically, `3.2.8.RELEASE`) and the now current version of Spring Framework `5.x`.

This is a significant and major version gap across 2 generations no less, and many things have changed in-between and since then.

Spring Framework 3.x and 4.x have also long been out of OSS as well as commercial [support](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#support).

The specific problem you are mentioning involving the Spring Framework's `BeanFactoryLocator` was addressed in [SGF-587](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-587) over 5 years ago. Spring (Data) *major.minor* versions are only supported for ~1.5 years.  An entire major generation even is only supported for roughly 3-4 years.